# How to shrink an ext4 partition from Windows?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, filesystems, ext4

My system has three primary partitions: two NTFS (one "system-reserved") for Windows 7 and one ext4 for Linux. How can I shrink the ext4 partition from Windows?

I've tried the built-in Disk Management tool as well as Paragon Partition Manager and MiniTool Partition Wizard, and neither tool seems able to shrink the ext4 partition. What can I do?

Comment: Why do you have to use Windows? There’s plenty of “live” systems available for both USB drives and CD/DVD.

Comment: You either need to add the drivers required to do this ( which will not happen through the built-in tool ) or use an OS that does.  The driver can be added through third-party tools.

Comment: Thanks but I was wondering how to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to do this for a Raspberry Pi drive. Using a boot loader to do it could cause issues because all my USB devices and hubs and my GPU need to be compatible. Or, I could do it in Windows with a known-working system.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you download Gparted or PartedMagic and create a boot disk; then you can shrink any partition you like.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question. The question was how to shrink an ext4 partition from Windows. You have suggested creating a boot disk and rebooting, leaving Windows behind.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton : What's the difference, does the partition need to be shrunk or not? I'm not arguing with you, go on and decrease my credits!

Comment: Your approach will certainly work, it's just that it doesn't solve the question posed by the original poster. I'm not sure why Morot needs this to happen in Windows.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.